# implementing application crashes intent

Tags: android

implement a code I found on how to pass variables from one class to another 
but to compile it gives me error and falls, leave the error

I believe the error is problem in implementing listview in fragment

```
  05-11 23:20:14.697  10975-10975/com.learn2crack.tab E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.learn2crack.tab, PID: 10975
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.learn2crack.tab.Categoria.onCreateView(Categoria.java:53)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:478)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16537)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5135)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16537)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5135)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16537)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5135)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16537)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1947)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1137)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1326)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1024)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5796)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:133)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this categoria.java

code class

```
 ListView Lv =(ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        Lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        // Listview on item click listener


            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem

                String tagID = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idCAT))
                        .getText().toString();


                // Starting single contact activity
                Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(),ListaCat.class);
                //in.putExtra(TAG_title, name);
                in.putExtra(TAG_ID, tagID);
                //.putExtra(TAG_description, description);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });
```

List items

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="name"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:textColor="#ff7900"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/idCAT"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

vista

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list" />
```

Comment: could you show us your code??

Comment: Post your **full** logcat...you are missing some important parts such as the exception. Also, what is at line 55 of `Categoria.java`?

Comment: that's the full logcat, on line 55 is this Lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

Comment: `ListView Lv =(ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list_item);` should be `ListView Lv =(ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);`. Not sure where `list_item` came from. And that is *not* your full logcat. In your logcat, where you see `at com.learn2crack.tab.Categoria.onCreateView(Categoria.java:55)`, before that is the exception.

Comment: Ok, what is at line 53? Do you now see where the it shows you the exception and what line it is on?

Comment: line 53,  Lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

Comment: Not sure how that can be lines 53 and 55 but still, see my previous comment about initializing your `ListView`

Comment: where the response goes below was copied, this ran lines

Comment: I don't know what that means but have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: implement it but still falls

Comment: Ok, same logcat output or something different?

Comment: yes,continues to give me line 53

Comment: @codeMagic because the problem will extend Fragment not of listFragment?

Answer (score 0):

first thing i can see is `view.findViewById(R.id.idCAT)`

replace it with only `view`

```
ListView Lv =(ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list_item);
    Lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    // Listview on item click listener


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem

           /* String tagID = ((TextView) view)
                    .getText().toString();*/
 TextView txt = (TextView) parent.getChildAt(position - lv.firstVisiblePosition()).findViewById(R.id.list_item);
 String tagId = txt.getText().toString();


            // Starting single contact activity
            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),ListaCat.class);
            //in.putExtra(TAG_title, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_ID, tagID);
            //.putExtra(TAG_description, description);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
```

What you get using `findViewById`?
and answer is `view`
so you dont can't get another view in view
you have to just cast that view to your `ListView`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, but I'm still with the same error

Comment: capture the id of an item and then pass it to another case

Comment: C:\Users\luis\SwipeTab\app\src\main\java\com\learn2crack\tab\Categoria.java
Error:(62, 74) error: cannot find symbol method firstVisiblePosition()
Error:(62, 72) error: local variable Lv is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final

Comment: declare lv as final `final ListView lv = ...`

Comment: will you?  TextView txt = (TextView) parent.getChildAt(position - lv.getFirstVisiblePosition()).findViewById(R.id.list_item);

Comment: Look at the logcat. The original problem is that `LV` is `null`!

Comment: @user3091574 `firstVisiblePosition` I red , `getFirstVisiblePosition()` gives me the option to switch to

Comment: I still have problems gives me error in line 53, that line is `Lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {`

Comment: @user3091574 because the problem will extend Fragment not of listFragment?

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
 Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(),ListaCat.class);
```

try this

```
Intent in = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),ListaCat.class);
```

Comment: I do not understand your change

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is your Listview not get ref from xml replace 
ListView Lv =(ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list_item); line to
ListView Lv =(ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list_item);
 then check it.